# converting script from matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab, octave

I have a bunch of matlab functions in a directory each of which only uses in-built matlab fcns (and not toolboxes) .... my question is if [oct2py](https://oct2py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/examples.html) would allow for the matlab scripts to run even if there isn't a matlab session running, i.e., I will be passing the data into the main matlab fcn that has other several smaller functions? also, would there be any issues since there are dependencies amongst the functions?

Finally, I would prefer converting the scripts entirely, e.g., [OMPC](http://ompc.juricap.com/), but, am not totally sure of using translators. thank you

Comment: Have you try writing the code in Python yourself?

Comment: Are you 100% that your matlab functions are 100% octave compatible? If not, then oct2py isn't really the way to go. If you are happy requiring a matlab installation as a dependency and licencing isn't a problem for your users, then there are projects similar to oct2py but specifically for interfacing with matlab from python. Otherwise, yes, 'translating' to pure python is the way to go (either by yourself or using OMPC ... I have not tried OMPC to be able to comment)